# Ajax call to [WebMethod] throws an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to send back SQL Server data as a JSON. At Button1 press an id is passed to a `[WebMethod]` from an Ajax Post in JSON form.

The `jsonobject` calls `jsondb.mdf` which exists with table: `jsondata` and columns `idd, datetime, col1, col2` and `col3` with data in them.

Default.aspx.cs

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string GetJSONdata(string id1)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["jsonobject"].ConnectionString;
        string cmdStr = "SELECT ([idd],[datetime],[col1],[col2],[col3]) FROM [jsondata] WHERE [idd]=@idd;";
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idd", id1);
                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        da.Fill(ds);
                        dt = ds.Tables[0];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

        List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> row;

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            row = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
            }

            rows.Add(row);
        }

        var json2 = serializer.Serialize(rows);
        return json2;
    }
```

Default.aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= Button1.ClientID %>").click(function () {
            var id = $("#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>").val();
            var data = { ID:id };
            var json1 = JSON.stringify(data);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Default.aspx/GetJSONdata",
                data: json1,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#<%= TextBox2.ClientID %>").val(result.ID);
                    $("#<%= TextBox3.ClientID %>").val(result.datetime);
                    $("#<%= TextBox4.ClientID %>").val(result.col1);
                    $("#<%= TextBox5.ClientID %>").val(result.col2);
                    $("#<%= TextBox6.ClientID %>").val(result.col3);
                },
                error: function (Msg) {
                    $("#<%= Label1.ClientID %>").text('failed:' + Msg.status +  '    response:' + Msg.responseText);

                }
            }); return false;
        });
    });
```

Error code:

> failed:500 response:{"Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027id1\u0027.","StackTrace":" at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}

Comment: Your parameter in your web service method is called `id1` but your JSON object has a property called `ID`. The names need to match.

Comment: I'm not sure. But you can try change `GetJSONdata(string id1)` to `GetJSONdata(string id)`

Comment: Your web method parameter is called `id1` but in your JS you are passing a param called ID. They need to match.

Answer (score 1):

```
 type: "POST",
                    async: false,
                    url: "Default.aspx/GetJSONdata",
                    data: "{id1:id}",// Change Name As Per You WEBMETHOD 
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    datatype: "json",
```

//Do this Change Might it will Help You

1) Create Class

```
public class ABC
        {
            public string idd{ get; set; }
            public string datetime{ get; set; }
            public string col1{ get; set; }
            public string col2{ get; set; }
            public string col3{ get; set; }

        }
```

2)Create Webmethod

```
  [webmethod]
  public static ABC[] GetJSONdata(string id1)
        {
            MasterLogic ml = new MasterLogic();
             DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["jsonobject"].ConnectionString;
    string cmdStr = "SELECT ([idd],[datetime],[col1],[col2],[col3]) FROM [jsondata] WHERE [idd]=@idd;";
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idd", id1);
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    dt = ds.Tables[0];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
            List<ABC> ProjectStatus = new List<ABC>();
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                ABC ps = new ABC();
              ps.id=Convert.ToInt32(dr["Columnname"]);
             // Do same To set value OF Properties
                ProjectStatus.Add(ps);

            }
            return ProjectStatus.ToArray();
        }
```

//Get Json on ASPX page

```
success: function (response) {
     for (var i = 0; i < response.d.length; i++) {
     //Write Your logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain how your post is an answer to the question, or why it should work. instead of throwing the same error as before

Comment: You must Pass Parameter that Define in you Web Method with SAME NAME

Comment: Please explain *in your answer* why this should work (it won't).  As it is, you are passing the string `id` to the parameter named `id1`, not the ID of the control, as the OP intended

Comment: I made all the changes and there is no errors but I am getting null on all of the outputs.  I think that means that the serialization is not working.

Comment: I just Edit My Answer According You New Error So please Check Out the Code It might Help You...

Comment: return ProjectStatus.ToArray(); does not work.  Error code:"Cannot implicitly convert type 'NameofFile.ProjectStatus[]' to 'string'."

Comment: i didn't get your error i convert projectstatus to Array and You Get Error  "Cannot implicitly convert type 'NameofFile.ProjectStatus[]' to 'string'."